# Start another application without loose focus

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigation, focus

please if someone can explain how I can start second application in Xamarin.Android without loosing focus of my application. When my application is started, I need to check if is second application is launched because second aplication is dependency of my application.

In my application, on event OnCreate I launch second application by folowing code:

```
Intent intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("packageNameOfAnotherApplication");

intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);

StartActivity(intent);
```

but after this, my application is in background and I need that my application stays in foreground (focused) that user don't see second application.

And also second application should be launched only with one instance, thats why I used "SingleTop".

Please info how I can do this.

Comment: You can not start another App's Activity without losing focus, what are you actually trying to accomplishment? i.e. If you are sharing/push/pulling data from the 2nd app, you can implement a ContentProvider in the 2nd app and consume it in the 1st.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Second application is not develop by me. I only use her for listening received broadcasts (barcode reader) that second application sends.

Comment: Assuming that barcoding app is using a Service/ForegroundService to provide broadcasts (and provide its scanning service). Kill the barcoding app and just try starting it via `adb am startservice .... ` if that is enough for that app to provide its scanning/broadcasts, if so, you can do that in your app via StartService ( https://www.bing.com/search?q=android+startService&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN )